# How to take average in a timeframe python?

Tags: python

I am  beginner in Python so I kindly ask your help. I would like to have a document where I have the first column as 2011.01 and the second column is the number of ARD 'events' in that month and the third column is the  average of all of the ARD displayed in that month. If not, that e.g. 2012.07 0 0

I've already tried for 3 hours and now I am getting nervous.

I really much appreciate your help

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std
from numpy import cov
from matplotlib import pyplot
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
from scipy.stats import spearmanr
data = pd.read_csv('ARD.txt',delimiter= "\t")

month = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
day = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31']
year = ['2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021']

ertek = data[:1].iloc[0].values
print(ertek)
print(data.head)

def list_to_string ( y, m, d):
    str = ""
    s = [y, m, d]
    str.join(s)
    return str

for x in year:
for y in month:
    for i in day:
        x = 1
        ertek = data[:x].iloc[0].values
        list_to_string(x, y, i)
        if ertek[0] == list_to_string[x, y, i]:
            print("")
            x += 1
        else:
            print("")
```

Result:

```
['2011.01.05.' 0.583333333]
<bound method NDFrame.head of              Date       ARB
0     2011.01.05.  0.583333
1     2011.01.06.  0.583333
2     2011.01.07.  0.590909
3     2011.01.09.  0.625000
4     2011.01.10.  0.142857
...           ...       ...
1284  2020.12.31.  0.900000
1285  2020.12.31.  0.900000
1286  2020.12.31.  0.900000
1287  2020.12.31.  0.900000
1288  2020.12.31.  0.900000

[1289 rows x 2 columns]>
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kókai Dávid\Desktop\python,java\python\stock-trading-ml-master\venv\Scripts\orosz\oroszpred.py", line 29, in <module>
   list_to_string(x, y, i)
   File "C:\Users\Kókai Dávid\Desktop\python,java\python\stock-trading-ml-master\venv\Scripts\orosz\oroszpred.py", line 21, in list_to_string
    str.join(s)
  TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

 Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `str` is a python type; it's not good practice to have variables with name-collisions with python types.

Comment: It looks like you may be making some assumptions about how many days there are in a month (does every month have 31 days? What does your code do for February/April/June/September/November?)

Comment: Would you double-check your formatting and indentation as provided in the question? It's not clear what is intended to be part of your `def list_to_string` function, or the intended indentation in your nested `for`-loops.

Comment: I imagine you'll be interested in the `pandas.DataFrame.rolling` function, along with the `.mean()` function. I'm happy to help figure that out!

Comment: Could you give an example of your intended input, your intended output, and what output your code is giving now?

Comment: `head` is a _method_. So instead of `print(data.head)` you should do `print(data.head())`.

Comment: You should set your date-column as index and then use `.resample('M').mean()` on the appropriate sub-frame of `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite certain I'm tracking your intent with the `list_to_string` function; if it's for string date comparison, let's sidestep that entirely by

```py
df.iloc[:,0] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:,0]
df.set_index('Date')
df['Month Average'] = df.Date.resample('M').mean()
```

Comment: Better: `df.iloc[:, 0] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, 0])`